# Ubuntu 23.04 installation problems

Tags: ubuntu, package

I had Ubuntu 22.10 and since March I ccouldn't find any living repositories in order to update any packages.

So in order to fix this I tried to update to 23.04, which seemed quite difficult.

Then, after following this tutorial, I was finally able to update Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04:

[https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-22-04-to-ubuntu-23-04](https://stackoverflow.com)

I've encountered several weird things after that:

- The Terminal background is white
- The initial screen was all blue, though I could fix that in Configuration
- I see a white square instead of a cursor when I point out of Mozilla Firefox
- I cannot see the sidebar and the Ubuntu Desktop options on Configuration don't appear
- There is no minimize option on any program I open

I have looked for some help online, but haven't found anything like this.

[image: white Terminal]

[image: white square instead of cursor. It's in the righ side of the screen]

You can also see the lack of minimize button on Firefox and Terminal

[image]

What can be the solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you consider using the legacy installer of Ubuntu, as it might be beneficial for your specific situation. By opting for the legacy installer, you may find a solution or workaround that addresses any challenges or issues you are facing. Additionally, I would like to inquire whether you have set up a dual boot configuration on your system, which involves installing and running multiple operating systems simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, I have dual boot on my computer. Do you think that might have anything to do with my issue? By the way, I just installed 22.04, as recommended by a friend, and it runs without big problems.
However, what might be the cause for the lack of repositories?
Thank you!